# Jqtransform bug in firefox and chrome

Tags: jquery, css

Basically, in firefox the text is pushed down where it overlaps the input border. I read that this can be fixed by changing the padding of .jqTransformInputInner div input to all 0px.It works, however it makes it misaligned in chrome.

How can I fix this?

Or is it possible to have two different padding values for the different browsers?

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me:

download the js from http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector

and use the followings in the jqtransform.css:

.ie .jqTransformInputInner div input {padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;}

.gecko .jqTransformInputInner div input {padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;}

.chrome .jqTransformInputInner div input {padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;}

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that chrome is being detected as safari and that this css tag affects the position of the text in the input field.

```
.jqTransformSafari .jqTransformInputInner div input {
```

just mess around with the top attribute.